# Swift sort an array and return an array of index and element

Tags: swift, sorting, indexing, filtering

I wish to sort an array, and return an array of indexes and elements within the sorted array;

ie:

```
var filtered = self.existingOrders.sorted(by: { (eo1:ExistingOrder, eo2:ExistingOrder) -> Bool in
                return (eo1.value < eo2.value)
            }).index(0, offsetBy: 0)
```

This just gives me an index of a specific number.

I would like a sorted array of elements and indexes; so I can grab the necessary index and do manipulations on them.

How do I make it so I can do;

```
// pseduocode:

var filtered:(Index, Element) = self.existingOrders.sortByLowest.return(flatMap(index, element))
```

or possibily even chain an enumerator to help give me a list of all items indexed; post-sort?

ie:

```
 let filtered = self.existingOrders.sorted(by: { (eo1:ExistingOrder, eo2:ExistingOrder) -> Bool in
                return (eo1.value < eo2.value)
            }).enumerated().flatMap({ (offset:Int, element:ExistingOrder) -> (Int, ExistingOrder) in
                return (offset, element)
            })
```

I wish to get a sorted array and return an index and element to my filter variable.

How do I accomplish this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you can use
`enumerated()` to get a sequence of offset/element pairs and sort
this according to the elements. Example:

```
let array = ["C", "A", "B"]

let sortedElementsAndIndices = array.enumerated().sorted(by: {
    $0.element < $1.element
})

print(sortedElementsAndIndices) // [(1, "A"), (2, "B"), (0, "C")]
```

The first element in each tuple is the index of the second tuple element in the original array.

In your case it would be something like

```
let sorted = self.existingOrders.enumerated().sorted(by: {
    $0.element.value < $1.element.value
})
```